# What do I need to do to make this transparency work

Tags: pdf, acrobat

I have a PDF, I know it has transparency but Acrobat pro renders the transparent portion solid. If I view it in chrome it looks right. And if I do an output preview and change the "Show" option to "Not DeviceCMYK" it previews the transparency, but this doesn't actually change the PDF and I can't figure out how to then just remove the CMYK so that it will be transparent.

[Here is the pdf again](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12253151/SODemo.pdf)

I've messed around for this a bit more. It looks like there is some knockout grouping, how can I change this in Acrobat?

I also seem be able to, in Acrobat, cut the image, then paste it back in and I get the transparency I need. What is this changing and how can I change this without having to cut, paste and re-position?

Comment: Are you programmatically creating the PDF?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yes, it's a watermark operation from Coldfusion. I don't know specifically what that does to the post script. I'm sure CF is probably doing something that is making a bad PDF, but since I can't change what CF does, and I can get Chrome to see that it's transparent and Acrobat to preview that it's transparent, I'm looking to see if there is something I can do in acrobat to actually make it print with the transparency.

Comment: Your link requires a dropbox login. Please allow access without requiring login.

Comment: That been said, the issue reminds of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155687/transparent-images-in-pdf) - there also Chrome displayed transparency but current Acrobat versions didn't... and it turned out that Acrobat was correct because knockout groups were used and transparency, therefore, shouldn't let knocked-out parts of the same group shine through but instead material behind that group (which was the white background in that case). Chrome seems to ignore knockout group settings.

Comment: @mkl fixed the link, drop box shut down the first one. Also knockout groups are not being used in mine, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @mkl - I guess knockout grouping is part of the problem, but how can that be changed in Acrobat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Acrobat pro renders the transparent portion solid. If I view it in chrome it looks right.

Just like in the case of [the question *Transparent images in PDF*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155687/transparent-images-in-pdf) the problem indeed is the knockout setting in a transparency group. Knockout settings seem to be ignored by some viewers, especially by the built-in Chrome PDF previewer, but correctly are respected by (current) Adobe Acrobat and Reader versions.

In contrast to the situation in that other question the group in question is not the page group but a group of a specific xobject. As that xobject contains both the transparent image and the image the OP wants to shine through, though, the observed issue is very similar.

> how can I change this in Acrobat?

I found no obvious way to edit transparency group settings in Acrobat. But I unfortunately only have version 9.5 here, maybe newer versions  allow that.

> I also seem be able to, in Acrobat, cut the image, then paste it back in and I get the transparency I need. What is this changing

Most likely this cuts the image out of the knockout transparency group shared by the images (the actual photo and the partially transparent pure black image you want to use for darkening), and pasting it back in results in those two images residing in different transparency groups; thus, they cannot knock each other out anymore.

> how can I change this without having to cut, paste and re-position

You can easily patch the PDF, thereby removing the **K** knockout entry from the transparency group definition, see below.

### PDF structure

The page 1 content of the PDF provided by the OP contains quite an object hierarchy:

- The immediate page content is not part of a transparency group and contains one image xobject **Im0** and two form xobjects **Fm1** and **Fm2**.
- The form xobject **Fm1** has a knockout transparency **Group** entry and contains one form xobject **HiQPdf_fnebajfcjaojkndmodkafcbjdllengkl**
- The form xobject **HiQPdf_fnebajfcjaojkndmodkafcbjdllengkl** does not have an own **Group** entry but is part of its parent's knockout transparency group; it contains two image xobjects **HiQPdf_fhhbjncnhiipkdhfommnfnbdgijfcjpi** and **HiQPdf_ibbjecddhjhkknkjbhmbefkgfbbmakep**, the latter one covering the top part of the former.
- The image xobject **HiQPdf_fhhbjncnhiipkdhfommnfnbdgijfcjpi** contains a photo of some house, no transparency.
- The image xobject **HiQPdf_ibbjecddhjhkknkjbhmbefkgfbbmakep** is black and has a transparency **SMask** with a value 162 everywhere.

The somewhat transparent image **HiQPdf_ibbjecddhjhkknkjbhmbefkgfbbmakep** and the image **HiQPdf_fhhbjncnhiipkdhfommnfnbdgijfcjpi** covered by it both are in the same knockout transparency group provided by **Fm1**. Thus, the transparency does not allow the house in **HiQPdf_fhhbjncnhiipkdhfommnfnbdgijfcjpi** shine through but what is behind **Fm1**.

But there is nothing behind **Fm1** which in PDF implies a white background. Combined with the blackness of **HiQPdf_ibbjecddhjhkknkjbhmbefkgfbbmakep** and a constant **SMask** value 162 this results in the gray bar you see in Adobe Reader:

[image: SODemo.pdf]

### Removing Knockout

The knockout transparency group dictionary of **Fm1** is in object `31 0`:

```
31 0 obj
<</K true/S/Transparency>>
endobj
```

By overwriting `/K true` with spaces the PDF is patched to have a non-knockout group here, and the result is:

[image: SODemo.pdf patched]

Comment: THANK YOU. Now I just need to figure out how to do that programatically and I'll be set.

Comment: *Now I just need to figure out how to do that programatically and I'll be set.* - For that you may want to ask a dedicated question indicating your choice of programming environment and PDF processing library.

Comment: Fortunately I was able to get that figured out, I already has a language specific question running and I get to answer it myself :)