# PDF Image corrupted in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, adobe-indesign

I have a link to download an image heavy PDF on my site. It works fine in Firefox and Safari. But the 2nd to last page is rendered wrong when using Chrome. The background behind some logos turns black instead of white making them unreadable.

It even displays wrong locally, when just pulling the file into the chrome browser.

Is there a possibly and issue when exporting the PDF from Indesign? Maybe the file is too large? Thanks for any advice.

[image: chrome screenshot here]

[Link to PDF here](https://elevarstudios.com/assets/download/ELEVAR-Brochure.pdf?)

Comment: Can you provide the PDF file? Hard to diagnose a file specific issue without the file.

Comment: Just as Ryan says, without the PDF this is pure guesswork. My guess (but this really is merely a guess...) would be that Knockout values are involved, something Chrome used to not support, also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22166681/1729265), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23512508/1729265), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23530616/1729265).

Comment: @mkl thanks for the heads up. I've added a link to the PDF in the description. The issue is with the 2nd to last page.

Comment: First observation: I loaded your PDF in Adobe Acrobat Pro (my old version 9.5) and immediately saved it again using save as. And the result also works with Chrome! The result file is only a bit shorter (by 30KB), so I doubt it is the size...